# How do I defeat the human?

Tags: yurivania-uhaul-of-the-night

In *[Yurivania: Uhaul of the Night](https://mxashlynn.itch.io/yurivania-1)*, after leaving the castle by jumping out a window, a skeleton named Tibby asked me to defeat a human. I found the human after heading to the right, but I can't figure out how to damage them. Jumping on the human's head just hurts me.

How do I defeat the human?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You start the game with a couple of objects in your inventory. Try using them and see what message you get. Could one of them be useful against a human?